# Embed external variable into sql select result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this particular use case where I have to add a string as a particular field one time for a row in an sql result set.

E.g. :-

I have the following result set:-

```
| id | Name | Year |
| 1  | ABCD | 2017 |
| 2  | EFGH | 2017 |
```

I have two string { a , b } which I need to embed into this result set as such without affecting the base table:-

```
| id | Name | Year | String |
| 1  | ABCD | 2017 |   a    |
| 2  | EFGH | 2017 |   b    |
```

How can I do this with php? or better, with sql?

Comment: What is `a` and `b` in a String?

Comment: they are just arbitrary strings which I have within php.

Comment: `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` up to what ?

Comment: Can you explain your problem with detail what actually you want?

Comment: I have some strings which I have in php. I want to embed each string into each row of a select result, put into a separate column without doing any insert to the base table.

Comment: If you're using PHP, do this in PHP.

Comment: Sure, will try to do it that way, then. @tadman